# Excel Internal Hyperlinks to Worksheets with Space in their Names

Tags: microsoft-excel, hyperlink

Good Day,

This is just a quick question. I'm creating hyperlinks on several worksheets to a Table of Contents (TOC) worksheet in an Excel workbook.  If this is easy to do by selecting all worksheets then deselecting the TOC worksheet, then add the link to one (all).

The question is I find it easy to do as long as there is no space in the worksheet being linked to.

ie. Table_Of_Contents works while Table of Contents doesn't.

The example below the TOC sheet is named Cases

```
=HYPERLINK(CONCAT("#","Cases","!A1"),"All Cases")
```

but if I wanted to call the TOC "List of Case" is there a trick.

Searching Google didn't really provide much.

I'm using Office Pro Plus (which is tagged 365, but the version were running is more like 2016 as it doesn't have XLOOKUP or UNIQUE etc.)

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: try =HYPERLINK(CONCAT("#","Cases","!"&A1"),"All Cases")

Comment: Thanks Peter, =HYPERLINK(CONCAT("#","Cases","!A1"),"All Cases") works, I'm more trying to determine if I could name Cases worksheet something "List of Cases" and use =HYPERLINK(CONCAT("#",List of Cases","!A1"),"All Cases") to work. If there is a space in the linked worksheet the formula won't work.     I'm trying to show some people how to use it, and am anticipating a question about a worksheet with spaces in the name and don't want to say it's not possible if it is.

Comment: Sorry Brad i completely miss read your question, when i get some free time will give this a proper look

Comment: Hi Peter, Don't worry about it it. I appreciate you taking a look regardless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using a sheet name with spaces, the sheet name needs to be contained in single quotes:

```
=HYPERLINK("#"&"'List of cases'!A1","All Cases")
```

OR if you want to use CONCAT:

```
=HYPERLINK(CONCAT("#","'List of cases'!","A1"),"All Cases")
```

Comment: Thanks that solved the issue

Comment: hi @BradR can you mark as correct

Comment: Thanks PeterH, not used to asking questions. Have a great day.